# Toggle Visibility - Hidden/reset when click outside

Tags: jquery, html

**How it works**

I currently have a list with Isotope which shows all categories of posts. When a category is clicked it shows all posts within that category. This works correctly. [Please see page if it's hard to understand](http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/spectra-norge/fyrverkeri).

```
<ul id="filters-undercat" class="luft underkategori">
     <li class="smoothtrans"><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected smoothtrans">Alle</a></li>
     <li class="smoothtrans"><a href='#' data-filter='.familiepakker' class="smoothtrans">Familiepakker</a></li>
     <li class="smoothtrans"><a href='#' data-filter='.markfyrverkeri' class="smoothtrans">Markfyrverkeri</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Show text within each category**

I also want a text to be shown that represent each category. This means that when a category is clicked it shows another div containing text.  This works partly. I have done this by using `onclick="toggle_visibility`

**JS**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
     if(e.style.display == 'none')
        e.style.display = 'block';
     else
        e.style.display = 'none';         
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="filters-undercat" class="luft underkategori">
         <li class="smoothtrans"><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected smoothtrans">Alle</a></li>
         <li class="smoothtrans"><a href='#' data-filter='.familiepakker' class="smoothtrans" onclick="toggle_visibility('familiepakker')">Familiepakker</a></li>
         <li class="smoothtrans"><a href='#' data-filter='.markfyrverkeri' class="smoothtrans" onclick="toggle_visibility('markfyrverkeri')">Markfyrverkeri</a></li>
</ul>
```

The text that is going to be shown in each category:

```
<div id="pakketekstholder">
        <div id="familiepakker" style="display:none;">Tekst om familie</div>
        <div id="markfyrverkeri" style="display:none;">Tekst om mark</div>
</div>
```

**The problem**

The problem is when a second cateogry is clicked, it also shows the first category text. And so on.

[Please see page if you have not done it yet](http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/spectra-norge/fyrverkeri)

**The solution**

The best solution would have been if another list is clicked, it was reset as default and then added another div.

Could you please provide a working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to all the categories, `"category"` for instance. You can then iterate over all of them and set visibility:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var all = document.getElementsByClassName('category');
   for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
      all[i].style.display = (all[i].id == id && all[i].style.display == 'none')
         ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uL4bbaz/)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your solution and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes to persist which container div to show.

Here I have used existing `data-filter='.familiepakker'` attribute and used it for element selection and added them as `class="familiepakker"` so that Class selector can be used.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#filters-undercat li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#pakketekstholder > div').not($(this).data('filter')).hide(); //Hide All divs
    $($(this).data('filter')).toggle(); //Toggle to indent container
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters-undercat" class="luft underkategori">
  <li class="smoothtrans"><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected smoothtrans">Alle</a>
  </li>
  <li class="smoothtrans"><a href='#' data-filter='.familiepakker' class="smoothtrans">Familiepakker</a>
  </li>
  <li class="smoothtrans"><a href='#' data-filter='.markfyrverkeri' class="smoothtrans">Markfyrverkeri</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="pakketekstholder">
  <div class="familiepakker" style="display:none;">Tekst om familie</div>
  <div class="markfyrverkeri" style="display:none;">Tekst om mark</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I could not get it to work correctly. Could you please take a look at page again? [Link to page] (http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/spectra-norge/fyrverkeri/)

Comment: @Olen, instead of `id="familiepakker"` use `class="familiepakker"` and also change other elements also

Comment: Thank you. However, I still can't get it to work correctly. By pressing "Alle" (meaning show all) it leads to a blank white page. By pressing "Familiepakker" it only shows the text, and no products... I have only changed "Familiepakker" and "Markfyrverkeri" in case it's not possible to solve the problem by the following method.

Comment: I used @David Hedlund's solution and it worked very well. I give you a upvote for very helpful helping, @Satpal! :)